# Where does the name Euler System come from?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology

I've recently been reading about Euler systems, and was curious where the name comes from.  In particular, while the notion of an Euler system is still not rigorously defined, does the idea resemble something of Euler's, or is the name purely coincidental?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it comes from "Euler factors."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_system explains the origin. 

Comment: What makes you say that the idea of an Euler system is not rigorously defined? See e.g. chapter 2 of Rubin's book "Euler systems".

Comment: I have looked through Rubin's book, and there does exist an attempt at a definition.  However, it does not capture the anti-cyclotomic Euler system that Kolyvagin defined (yes, Rubin does include that later too...).  But there are so few examples of Euler systems, that it seems unlikely Rubin's captures precisely the properties to describe such a phenomenon.

Comment: I guess it's a question of semantics--I should have been more precise.  Thanks for the responses btw!  I did not think of looking at wikipedia :P

Comment: Should we consider the question answered?

Comment: You could also have a look at the introduction of Kato's article in Astérisque 295 for a nice overview of the ideas behind introducing Euler systems.

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/q/11405